# ruby mechanize website scraping always returns javascript data only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri, mechanize

I am working  with mechanize gem to scrape website content which has login authentication . I could able to login successfully using mechanize gem but after submit the form using mechanize the server response is only of javascript content , all I could see in the response page is javascript content I do not find any of html data , I am not sure what wrong I did .here is my code please look at it

```
agent = Mechanize.new { |a|
 a.follow_meta_refresh = true
}

agent.get("https://www.somewebsite.com/signin.html")

form = agent.page.forms.first
form.username = 'username@mail.com'
form.password = 'password'
page = form.submit

puts page.body ## returns javascript content only
```

but the original site has dashboard content which I want get it .

Can anyone help me , thanks in advance .

Comment: Are you sure the site you're looking at doesn't build the html client side?

Comment: Its huge website and has lot of content on the url I am sending through mechanize

Comment: Can you please help how to know whether website has restriction for content scraping or not through mechanize gem or any in ruby

Comment: On the website, [view the page source](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000746.htm).

Comment: @PrakashMurthy how to know it programatically in ruby or how to know it on the page source ?

Comment: @PrakashMurthy I checked page source ,yes its the same content what I get through the mechanize gem . page source shows me only javascript content . what it means can you please explain me ?

Comment: What @FrederickCheung suggested initially: The site builds html client side. The javascript builds the page content. Not much you can do in terms of scraping the site. See if they provide an API or a rss feed that you can use.

Comment: Oh thank you very much to both of you , they are not providing any api that is why I decided to go with scraping but now I got to know by your words its also not possible

Comment: I recently posted an answer to a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28071251/scraping-external-website-but-returns-you-must-use-a-javascript-capable-browser/28130892#28130892

Comment: Yes the problem was solved however I forgot to answer here , I used capybara-webkit support to solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used capybara-webkit to solve my problem