# Scraping external website but returns "You must use a JavaScript capable browser with this site." error

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, web-scraping

I'm using the rake task in Ruby on Rails. I have a website where I need to log-in in order to scrape the site. I filled out the form.

```
form[:login] = user_name
form[:pw] = password
form.submit
```

this returns the error

```
#<Mechanize::Page
 {url
  #<URI::HTTPS:0x007fa36a0037b8 URL:https://pulse2.com/system/JSAuth/NoScript.html>}
 {meta_refresh}
 {title "You must use a JavaScript capable browser with this site."}
 {iframes}
 {frames}
 {links}
 {forms}>
```

This is weird, because a) Can I turn on JS capability for the **scraper** b) Is this an problem with the site itself?

[EDIT] More information. When I look at the form it looks like this. One thing to note is the {action "/system/JSAuth/NoScript.html"}. I believe this is the reason why I can't submit my action. IS there a way to get around this??

```
#<Mechanize::Form
   {name "mainform"}
   {method "POST"}
   {action "/system/JSAuth/NoScript.html"}
   {fields
    [hidden:0x3fc5b7d7d8b0 type: hidden name: referer value: ]
    [hidden:0x3fc5b7d7d75c type: hidden name: VerLoginAttempt value: 1]
    [hidden:0x3fc5b7d7d608 type: hidden name: FormName value: LoginMain]
    [text:0x3fc5b7d7d4b4 type: text name: VerLoginID value: ]
    [field:0x3fc5b7d7d360 type: password name: VerPassword value: ]}
   {radiobuttons}
   {checkboxes
    [checkbox:0x3fc5b7d7d234 type: checkbox name: RCRememberMe value: false]}
   {file_uploads}
   {buttons [submit:0x3fc5b7d7d090 type: submit name:  value: Login]}>
```

Comment: You'll likely need to modify the user-agent to get past that.  Not sure how you would do that in rails

Comment: What would you modify the user-agent to be?

Comment: I usually pick firefox: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Comment: Hey I changed my user agent to firefox as you mentioned above. But I'm still getting the same "JS capable browser error"        `agent.user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; rv:36.0)`

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically interact with a page that requires Javascript for core features you'll need to use a 'headless browser'.

You should look into [Watir](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watir), [Selenium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selenium_(software)) and [phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org).